# Way to Reboot and Restore All Programs, ETC on Restart

Tags: windows-7, windows

I am looking for a way that I can reboot my desktop pc and have it restart in the same state as when it shut down, e.g. all programs/files I had opened, etc.

I guess I am looking to do something similar to a hibernate sleep/wake on a notebook.

Is this possible on a desktop pc with a full reboot?  Is there any software for this?

I am NOT looking to recover any UN-Saved work, etc, but rather, to restore my desktop to its same state e.g. same programs and documents open, etc.

I am running a windows based x64 PC with windows 7 professional.

Comment: This is exactly what hibernate is suppose to do.  What does hibernate not do?

Comment: Well, hibernate it. It's not only for laptops.

Comment: Hibernate is not a full reboot. Am I wrong?

Comment: @robarwebservices Yes. Hibernate completely saves your computers state and powers off. You can then power back on and restore the state. The only difference between this and a restart is that you have to push the power button in between. Related: http://superuser.com/questions/644690/why-is-hibernation-still-used

Comment: Good read. So lets say windows update wants a reboot. Will hibernation be sufficient to satisfy windows update's reboot requirement?